# Account ownership has been changed automatically

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, workflow, production

Hi Friends I'm facing a critical issue.like lot of accounts had ownership changes automatically.And all these accounts are showing account owner last modified by this user.We didn't set up any sharing rules or field update in accounts.Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

And we write an apex class in a custom object called bi in that object we have a common field in this and account.based on this field whenever it updated we automatically update the same field in account.
But we didn't touch anything related  to change the ownership of the account.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: did you ask the user what s/he did?  Note that that user had to be the running user making the change if lastModifiedBy is that user.

Comment: Ya in account history it showing account owner is changed by this particular Id.And how can they change 600 accounts in a single day and they didn't use any bulk update tools @cropredy

Comment: Hmm --- do you have any VF controllers, workflow, processes, or triggers that execute account ownership changes? Is it possible that your user executed a mass change of some other field X in an enhanced list view that fired the apex/workflow/process/trigger that inadvertently did mass updates. Or maybe you have a flow that is not properly constrained.